# ConTeXt: \part without blank page

Tags: sectioning, context

According to the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/part):

> By default `\part` generates no title because most of the times these require special attention and a specific design. In the background however the partnumbering is active and carries out several initializations. The other section commands are set up to typeset a title.

What if I want to use the `\part{}` command but do not want it to produce a blank page? Instead, I want it to produce no page at all.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must admit that this is somewhat confusing. Part of the confusion is that, by default, `part` does not show the head title, so one has to guess what is going on. If you set `placehead=yes` in Henri Menke's code, you will see what is happening. **The page is not produced by `\part` but is produced by the subsequent `\chapter`**

In ConTeXt you can control the page break between a section head and its successor (i.e., page break between part and chapter or the page break between chapter and section) using the `continue` key. For the ease of explanation, I'll restrict to the higher level heading as `part` and the lower level heading as `chapter`, but the same applies for any two consecutive levels.

If we have

```
\setuphead[chapter][continue=yes, page=yes]
```

(which is the default), then there will be a page break between the part title and the chapter title *even if there is no text after the part title*. On the other hand, if we set

```
\setuphead[chapter][continue=no, page=yes]
```

then the page break at the beginning of the chapter will be suppressed if it comes immediately after a part title.

So, all you need to do in your code is to set

```
\setuphead[chapter][continue=no]
```

Here is a full minimal example:

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [
    continue=yes,
  ]

\starttext

\startpart[title=Part One]
  \startchapter[title=Chapter One]
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter[title=Chapter Two]
  \stopchapter
\stoppart

\startpart[title=Part Two]
  \startchapter[title=Chapter One]    
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter[title=Chapter Two]
  \stopchapter
\stoppart

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `page=no` in the setup for `part`.  For reasons I don't understand, this does not work on the first page of a document, but I consider this a minor issue because the first page is usually the titlepage.  I asked on the mailing list anyway (https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/090445.html).

Hans responded to my question with a list of possible fixes, which I quote here:

> this relates to the fact that there has to be some node on the page
>   that  registers the part information and as chapter flushes a page
>   that one  ends up on a page then
>
> ```
> % solution 1:
>
> \setuphead
>    [part]
>    [page=no,
>     placehead=hidden]
>
> \setuptexttexts
>    [\synchronizehead{part}]
>
> % solution 2:
>
> \setuphead
>    [part]
>    [page=no,
>     placehead=hidden]
>
> \appendtoks
>     \synchronizehead{part}%
> \to \everybeforepagebody
>
> % solution 3 (new in beta):
>
> \setuphead
>    [part]
>    [placehead=section]
> ```
>
> This will delay the flush till the next section head gets place. It's 
>   still not 100% predictable but it might work out ok in most cases.

Comment: The [ConTeXt wiki page about `setuphead`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead) is indeed unclear about the `page=no` keyword. And you are right, I reproduced the same issue: the `\part{}` commands did not produce any page except for the first `\part{}` which produced a blank page.

Comment: @ArnaudLasnier Almost.  It's not the first `\part`, it's only if the `\part` is the very first thing in the document.  If you add content before the first `\part` the blank page is gone.

Comment: @HenriMenke: You can add `placehead=yes` in your code to see what is happening. See my answer for details.